# How to migrate Joomla K2 to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migration, joomla-k2

I'm new in WordPress and Joomla and need to move the content from a Joomla site to a new WordPress one.

I found some plugins that help with it but all of them have a premium function who blocks me.

I Used FG Joomla To Wordpress plugin, but it did not migrate the images.

Note: the Joomla site, has 500+ posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it in a creative way.

The first issue were that k2 content can not be migrated to joomla for free if you want to move the content images too.
The first step was generate an RSS XML with all the posts and try to import them into my wordpress site.

To import them in wordpress I used [WP All Import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/)
This plugin moved the content from joomla to wordpress in some minutes INCLUDING THE IMAGES!
Nice!
But the images were linked to the joomla domain.

Our next step is retrieving each post image from joomla to wordpress and fix the links.

For this task I used [Auto Upload Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-upload-images/) 
Its process take about 10 minutes or more, but with amazing results.

The last step was to use the image of each post as excerpt.
Unfortunately I did not find plugins to do it, so it was a manual process.

Hope to be helpfull!